WPF Window with WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW Appears in Alt+Tab After Explorer.exe Restart When Launched with UI Access Token
I'm experiencing an unexpected behavior with a WPF window that's created with WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style when the application is launched with UI Access token privileges.
Issue Description:
A window with WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style unexpectedly appears in Alt+Tab after explorer.exe is restarted, but only when the application is launched with UI Access token. This doesn't occur when running the application directly.
Steps to Reproduce:

Start WPF application through a service using SetTokenInformation with TokenUIAccess
Create transparent, topmost window with WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style
Kill explorer.exe from Task Manager (Details tab)
Start explorer.exe using "Run new task"
Press Alt+Tab - window appears despite WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style

Window Styles Verification:
I verified using Spy++ that the styles remain unchanged after explorer.exe restart: https://i.sstatic.net/9roQafKN.png
The image shows Window Styles (0x680000) and Extended Styles (0x80A8) remain consistent before and after reproducing the issue, confirming WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW is still applied.
Code:
// Setting UI Access token
uint dwUIAccess = 1;
SetTokenInformation(hUserToken, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenUIAccess, ref dwUIAccess, sizeof(uint));

// Window styles
var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
var extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);

